# Digital signature verification - WinVerifyTrust keeps returning true

Tags: c#, cryptography, digital-signature

I am using WinVerifyTrust method of WinTrust.dll to verify if the digital signature of my dll is valid. But if I create my own certificate and a self-signed certificate authority and add it to the root store on my machine, WinVerifyTrust() still returns true.

Is there any other option to verify if my digital signature is valid or not?

P.S. Cannot use X509Certificates.Verify() method.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You are adding *more trust points* to your machine and something that already verifies still verifies? That sounds rather logical to me. You need to remove trust points to let it fail. Or are we all misunderstanding you? Add more detail!

Comment: @JohnSaunders Added more detail to the title. Just "Digital signature verification" doesn't really show what the question is about.

Answer (score 2):

WinVerifyTrust will always check the store for verifying a digital signature. Adding the root and cert to the TRUSTED root store implies that you trust those certificates and therefore the signatures. If you were to remove those certificates from the Trusted Store, then the verification should fail (depending on the flags you set). Try looking at [WinVerifyTrustEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388209(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Agreed with your comment. But in this case, if any hacker does the same WinVerifyTrust would return success. And that's what I don't want. I want to check if the file is digitally signed by an authenticate source.

Comment: You can build a policy that is applied to the trust verification so that it will restrict to whatever you define is the authenticated source.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using an external tool, i recommend using sysinternal's [sigcheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck). it is tiny, reliable and easy to use. it can export the results to a csv file if you prefer.